# How to specify mapping rule for bunch of properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 2 classes and want to configure mapping from one to another

```
public class Customer
{
   public long CustomerId{get;set;}
   public string ShippingAddres{get;set;}
   public string BillingAddress{get;set;}
   public DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
}

public class Item2
{
   public long customer_id{get;set;}
   public string shipping_addres{get;set;}
   public string billing_address{get;set;}
   public DateTime date_of_birth {get;set;}
}
```

I tried to search the answer but all answers that I find tell to map fields manually:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.customer_id));
```

I don't want to map each property manually, since I have a lot of properties. I want to configure some rule:

*to split property name by '_' and join strings to CamelCase*

or in pseudo code:

```
cfg.AddConditionalObjectMapper().Where((source, destination) => s.Name.Replace("(_)([a-z])","\U1") == d.Name );
```

The question is not about the Regex, I need to know how to configure such rules in Auto-mapper?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to configure it, but this method is not universal:

```
            cfg.AddMemberConfiguration().AddName< ReplaceName >( _ => _.AddReplace( "_", "" ) );
            cfg.AddMemberConfiguration().AddName< CaseInsensitiveName >();
```